# Чтение из базы данных

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Eсть база данных VPN в ней таблица accounting_data надо считать в ней определенные столбцы.
Создаем подключение через entity.

1 контекст данных

```
public class accounting_dataContext : DbContext
{
    public accounting_dataContext() : base("VPN")
    { }
    public DbSet<accounting_data> accounting_data { get; set; }
}
```

2 описываем класс

```
public class accounting_data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string User_Name { get; set; }
}
```

3 пробуем получить данные из первой строки

```
using (accounting_dataContext db = new accounting_dataContext())
{
     var accounting = db.accounting_data
         .Select(c => new
         {
             Id = c.Id,
             User_Name = c.User_Name
          })
          .FirstOrDefault();                    
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

И получаю пустой объект accounting = null где ошибка?

что бы было понятнее вот так выглядят столбцы данных[image: введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D9Sl.png)

Comment: `DbSet<accounting_dataContext> _accounting_data` тут должно быть `DbSet<accounting_data> _accounting_data`

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, в каждой таблице должен быть описан первичный ключ, чтобы EF мог работать. Иначе ему непонятно, как записи идентифицировать.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten спасибо ошибку уже не выдал, но accounting все равно null.

Comment: @CrazyElf он и описан это Id

Comment: `public DbSet<accounting_data> accounting_data`?

Comment: @tym32167 в чем вопрос?

Comment: у вас таблица `accounting_data`, а свойство `_accounting_data`, попробуйте переименовать свойство или вручную прописать таблицу.

Comment: @tym32167 не помогло все равно var accounting = null

Answer (score 1):

Сами ентити нужно тоже описать. Как они представлены в базе так же как и ключи.
Используйте скафолд для того, что бы получить аклуальный контекст бд и все.

В Visual Studio: Package Manager Console (обычно в вкладках снизу).
Нужно указать параметры вашей базы данных и параметров авторизации к ней:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell

Пример:
scaffold-dbcontext "data source={{data_source}};initial catalog={{db_name}};persist security info={{True/False}};user id={{user_name}};password={{password}}" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir ChangesFew -tables {{shema}}.{{TableName}}, {{shema}}.{{TableName}} -Force